# Is an user can see only committed data in the same session?

Tags: oracle

Is there any way to see only committed data only in the same session.
Like
User A updated table with 10 rows and committed.
then again updated 20 rows but not committed, so here User  A should only see committed data (10 Updated rows)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to achieve this.

Comment: You can set the database isolation level to READ COMMITTED, then you will only be able to get the committed data while querying the database.

Thanks

Comment: For Oracle another session can only see commited data. the OP is asking about the session that is doing the modifications.

Comment: This is not about achieving the same, i am asking whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to (ab)use an autonomous transaction to accomplish this. Just run the query in a function with PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION and it will only see commited data.

Answer (score 0):

Yep,

You want to use a save point.

[A better link on save points](http://www.rampant-books.com/t_garmany_20_rows_rollback_partial.htm)

[Save point link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_savepoint.htm)

A save point will allow you to save after a part of a transaction is complete. Then if the second part is rolled back you will keep your changes before the save point and lose the ones after the save point.

Comment: Sorry, I think i missed the point about being within the same session.